# Try Catch en ASP clásico

Tags: asp, vb6, try-catch

Estoy modificando un proyecto realizado en asp clásico con Visual Basic 6 y necesito capturar un error.

En concreto, el error se genera por estas lineas:

```
dim strResult, split1, split2  
strResult = FuncionQueDevuelveUnXML() 
split1 = Split(strResult,"</a:AccessToken>")(0)
split2 = Split(split1,"<a:AccessToken>")(1)
```

El caso en el que falla y que me gustaría capturar es cuándo **no existe** el tag `AccessToken`.

Cómo podéis ver actualmente no hay ningún control y la página genera un error 500 (**muy feo**)

Sé que *podría* realizar un `InStr` para comprobar si existe el tag:

```
if InStr(strResult,"<a:AccessToken>") < 1 Then
    'No existe el tag
else
    'Si existe el tag
end if
```

Pero quería saber si se puede realizar un `try catch` para capturar ***cualquier*** tipo de error.

Aunque no sea con `try catch` en sí pero algo parecido, la verdad es que desconozco si existe algo así.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Deberías utilizar la instrucción On Error. Algo así:

```
Dim strResult, split1, split2
strResult = FuncionQueDevuelveUnXML()
On Error Resume Next ' Si hay un error continúa con la siguiente isntrucción
Err.Clear()
split1 = Split(strResult,"</a:AccessToken>")(0)
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    On Error Goto 0 ' Para que no omita los errores de aquí en adelante
    ' Código para tratar el error
Else
    On Error Goto 0 ' Para que no omita los errores de aquí en adelante
    split2 = Split(split1,"<a:AccessToken>")(1)
End If
```

Para habilitar el control de errores con la instrucción On Error itenes 3 opciones:

1. GoTo [nº de línea]: el control salta a la línea especificada cuando se produce un error
2. GoTo [etiqueta]: el control salta a la línea con la etiqueta especificada cuando se produce un error
3. Resume Next: el control continúa en la siguiente instrucción cuando se produce un error

Cuando has habilitado el control de errores con una de estas 3 opciones, una vez finalizado el bloque en el que quieres controlar los errores (el código que normalmente tendrías en un try) puedes (o más bien deberías) utilizar la instrucción On Error GoTo 0 para deshabilitar el control de errores.

Puedes encontrar información sobre la instrucción On Error en la documentación de MSDN:
[Instrucción On Error (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/5hsw66as.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: como funciona eso del `goto 0`? No lo acabo de entender!

Comment: Edito la respuesta para ampliar la explicación